# What happens when Q3 and Max are the same in a box plot?

Tags: graphing-functions, descriptive-statistics

If a set of numbers was as follows: {7,8,8,10,11,13,13,13}, then the minimum value would be 7, Q1 (quarter one) would be 8, the median (Q2) would be 10.5, the Q3 would be 13, and the max would be 13.

How would this be shown on a box plot? Since the maximum value and Q3 are the same, would there just not be an extension of the box?

Can somebody explain to me how this would be plotted?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, your plot would just end at the third quartile:

[image]

http://www.imathas.com/stattools/boxplot.html